# File upload using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restful

I am trying to implement a python API in order to upload a file on my server but for an unknown reason, it doesn't run.

From my understanding, the app.py is not recognised

Here is my API.py

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
import sqlite3
import uuid
import os
import csv
import urllib.request
import threading
import queue as Queue
import subprocess
import json
import re
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)

class upload(Resource):
    def post(self):
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

    def allowed_file(filename):
        return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

    def upload_file():
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            resp = jsonify({'message' : 'No file part in the request'})
            resp.status_code = 400
            return resp
        file = request.files['file']
            int = str(request.form['int']) #true or false

        if file.filename == '':
            resp = jsonify({'message' : 'No file selected for uploading'})
            resp.status_code = 400
            return resp
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))  

                return json.dumps(data),   200
        else:
            resp = jsonify({'message' : 'Allowed file types are doc, etc.'})
            resp.status_code = 400
            return resp


api.add_resource(upload, "/api/v1/upload")
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Here is my app.py

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/xxxx/xxx/upload'
app = Flask(__name__)
#app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

Can you please help? Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you executing this?  It looks like `API.py` is an almost complete application, which could be executed with `python API.py`.  The only thing it's missing are the configuration values you set in your `app.py`.  You essentially have two applications here:  The first a full app without the config set.  The second an app with the configuration values set, but nothing else.

Comment: Is it possible to merge both applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment, it looks like you have two sepearate applications here.

I would just stick with the first one `API.py`, but you'll need to move the lines where you set the config variables into `API.py`:

So after this line in `API.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Immediately set the config values:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/xxxx/xxx/upload'
#app.secret_key = "something super secret"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

Then execute with:

```
python API.py
```